# How to retrieve records and also a field value in jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Consider following entity:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String family;
    //getters and setters
}
```

and sql:

```
select * 
from (select row_.*, first_Value(rownum) over (order by rownum desc) countـ
      from (select * from user) row_)
```

as you may guess the result set of sql consists of four columns:

```
id, name, family, countـ
```

I retrieve user table records as a list of user by:

```
String myQuery = "select * from (select row_.*, first_Value(rownum) over (order by rownum desc) count_
      from (select * from user) row_)"
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(myQuery, User.class);
List<User> users = query.getResultList();
```

Now the question is that how could I retrieve list of users and also count value just by calling getResultList() or any other hibernate equivalents once?

I use Oracle 11g and Jpa (Hibernate implementation 3.6)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is "builder" in your code?

Comment: sorry, I replaced it with myQuery...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "count" is a reserved word. And I would reorganize your query like this:

```
String myQuery = "SELECT "
        + "id, "
        + "name, "
        + "family, "
        + "cnt "
        + "FROM ("
            + "SELECT "
            + "user.*, "
            + "first_Value(rownum) over (order by rownum desc) AS cnt "
            + "FROM "
            + "user "
        + ")";
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(myQuery);
    List<Object[]> resultList = query.getResultList();
```

Of course you can use * instead of "id, name, family, cnt", too.